# Is infinite product of nilpotent groups nilpotent?

Tags: group-theory, solvable-groups, nilpotent-groups

Is infinite product of nilpotent (solvable) groups nilpotent (solvable)?

(I known they are true for finite cases)

Answer (score 7):

No to both. Take a product of groups $G_n$ which are $n$-step nilpotent (resp. $n$-step solvable) but not $n-1$-step nilpotent (resp. $n-1$-step solvable). However, this is true if (and only if!) the nilpotence (resp. solvability) degree is uniformly bounded.

Comment: How to prove this?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I don't have enough rep. to comment the following remark.</strike>

> <strike>Each term of the lower central series (resp. derived series) commutes with an arbitrary cartesian product.</strike>

<strike>This also proves the last assertion of Qiaochu.</strike>

I think a correct argument is the following.

> The cartesian product $\prod G_i$ satisfies a law $w$ if and only if 
>   each $G_i$ satisfies $w$.

Nilpotent groups of class at most $c$ are precisely the groups satisfying the law $[x_1,\ldots,x_{c+1}]=1$.

Comment: This is **false**! In general you have $$[\prod G_i,\prod G_i]\subseteq \prod [G_i,G_i]$$but equality need not hold. Take $G_i$ to be free of countable rank, with free generating set $x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,x_3,y_3,\ldots$. Take the element on the right hand side whose $n$th entry is $[x_1,y_1]\cdots[x_n,y_n]$. This element is not on the left hand side.

Comment: @Arturo: Oops, sorry! And thanks! Sometimes one can write very stupid things.

Comment: No problem; I even reviewed a published paper once that made the same incorrect assertion. In general, for any set of words $W$, we have $W(\prod G_i)\subseteq \prod W(G_i)$. If all $G_i$ satisfy $W$, then this implies $\prod G_i$ satisfies $W$; the converse also holds, but it does not follow from the simple inclusion.